# Android SQLite fast Date between search

Tags: android, database, performance, sqlite, date

I have a huge performance issue when it comes to an SQLite Query with date ranges.

In my application I have a database with a couple of thousands of records of sites. These sites are visitable but not the whole year. Each of those sites can define up to three ranges in which is is visitable. Therefore I created an SQLite Table with following columns: *open1*, *close1*, *open2*, *close2*, *open3* and *close3* (amongst others)

Application users can enter a time range in which they want to visit a site, e.g. 2014.01.01 - 2014.01.07

Now when I perform a search without restricting the time it is pretty fast.
But when I use the opening time as search criteria, the search takes up to about 7 seconds on a fast emulator. I do not even want to test this on a real device :)

The entries in the columns *open* and *close* are of type *DATETIME* and look like: *2014-01-01*

My current query is as follows:

```
    SELECT open1,close1,open2,close2,open3,close3 FROM sites WHERE (
      ( ( strftime('%Y-%m-%d', '2014-01-01') BETWEEN open1 AND close1 ) AND ( strftime('%Y-%m-%d', '2014-01-07') BETWEEN open1 AND close1 ) )
      OR
      ( ( strftime('%Y-%m-%d', '2014-01-01') BETWEEN open2 AND close2 ) AND ( strftime('%Y-%m-%d', '2014-01-07') BETWEEN open2 AND close2 ) )
      OR
      ( ( strftime('%Y-%m-%d', '2014-01-01') BETWEEN open3 AND close3 ) AND ( strftime('%Y-%m-%d', '2014-01-07') BETWEEN open3 AND close3 ) )
    )
```

Is there a simple way to improve the performance?

Notice: I tried using utc values in *long* format for *open* and *close* but this is not really debuggable.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: not debuggable if you don't format them, but clearly more efficient, in particular with an index

Comment: so you're saying that I should use *long* instead?

Comment: i would, yes. it makes simpler request easier to optimize (easier to see what index to create)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if it is more efficient but it can not hurt to simplify the query :

```
( ( strftime('%Y-%m-%d', '2014-01-01') BETWEEN open1 AND close1 ) AND ( strftime('%Y-%m-%d', '2014-01-07') BETWEEN open1 AND close1 ) )
```

is equivalent to :

```
( strftime('%Y-%m-%d', '2014-01-01') >= open1 AND strftime('%Y-%m-%d', '2014-01-07') <= close1 )
```

as long as the first date ('2014-01-01' in this case) is before the second ('2014-01-07'), i.e. you have :

`open*` <= `first` <= `second` <= `close*`

Comment: That is a great idea, how could i not have seen this myself? :) I will give this a shot right away and report the result, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you will find that a real device performs much better than the emulator.

Now, on to the real meat of the question. You should try creating indexes for those columns used in the `WHERE` clause (`open1`, `close1`, etc.). You can find plenty of tutorials on how to do this. Briefly, though, indexes help the database engine to find matching records quickly.

Try something like:

```
CREATE INDEX visitableIndex ON sites (open1, close1, ...)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I applied an index on to the open and close columns and it helped speed up the process by about 50% (not measured)